# Do aggregates have to be strongly consistent?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, event-sourcing, eventual-consistency, dddd

Everything I have read on DDD implies that state within aggregates must be strongly consistent.

This implies that if one required redundancy, then only strongly-consistent replication can be used (such as 2PC, 3PC or Paxos).

Are you allowed to use eventually consistent replication like multi-master or master-slave? If you did use them, is what you have still an 'aggregate' in DDD terms? Is this a common thing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aggregate itself needs to be consistent, however related aggregates can be eventually consistent with respect to each other. In fact, eventual consistency is a common paradigm in DDD within distributed scenarios. The aggregate can be thought of as a consistency boundary. This means that an aggregate is defined in terms of what must be consistent rather than being a pure reflection of reality.

As an example, a behavior on an aggregate can publish a domain event which is then published externally. An out of band handler for that event can bring the entire system into a consistent state eventually. Many times, eventual consistency is a perfectly acceptable business constraint, especially since eventual consistency is far more prevalent in reality.

Take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011) for more on this.

**UPDATE**

Eventually consistent redundancy of aggregates should be evaluated on a case by case basis. Some aggregates will be well-suited to conflict resolution, perhaps with natural compensation actions. These types of conflicts will resolve in ways similar to CQRS-style conflicts where compensation actions are be required to bring the system into a consistent state. As in CQRS, the effects of eventual consistency should be discussed with domain experts.

Comment: You have described a textbook definition of DDD aggregates, confirming even more the intro in my question. However, what about redundancy of aggregates, or more specifically: how do you handle having redundant copies hosted in disparate datacenters for geolocation needs?

Comment: Tasks such as synchronization across data stores should be handled by repositories or possibly services (a repository is a much more standard approach IMHO) - what's in the domain is simply business rules stating what an entity is and and how it transforms.